# Install guide for Ubuntu 18

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I tried `sudo snap install bitcoin-core`, which worked but I've read that it cannot be trusted, so I uninstalled it

the developer, bitcoincore.org, doesn't seem to maintain a binary for Ubuntu (or any other distribution) but provides a tar file.  they supply no instructions for how to install the software and I can't seem to find anything simple.  all I want is to install a running node (so there should be a startup script with SysV/InetD/startup, or whatever system Ubuntu is inclined to use now for automatically running services at boot-time)

can anyone point me to a working guide?

Comment: I haven't used the Snap Store installer, but it seems to be endorsed by the Bitcoin Core devs and listed as an installation option on their website. Where are you seeing that it can't be trusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run bitcoin node on an ubuntu machine, it is always recommend to build it from the source code itself. That way you can be almost 100% sure of its authenticity.

Start with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libboost-all-dev libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev libqt4-dev libminiupnpc-dev libtool libevent-dev automake autoconf pkg-config bsdmainutils
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
cd bitcoin
./autogen.sh
./configure.ac
make
make install (optional)
```

After compiling process is completed:

```
cd src/
sudo cp ./bitcoind /usr/bin/
sudo cp ./bitcoin-cli /usr/bin/
mkdir ~/.bitcoin
nano ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Add your RPC user and RPCpassword value in bitcoin.conf file, save, exit.

```
bitoind -daemon
```

Your node will start syncing in background.

Comment: that's disappointing.  I get the value of using source code but the publisher could easily create a binary and save everyone the trouble of having to install all the necessary tools and do the compilation

Comment: I won't accept this good answer in hopes of a better one :)

Comment: As far as I know, they do release binary versions for easy installations. But for production, most of the developers prefer getting source code from Master and compile it themselves.

Comment: fair enough.  I'll accept this as the authoritative answer.  if one has a larger number of VMs to install on, I suppose one can always compile in one box and distribute the binaries